# How to use Httpclient in java to send post request with complex requestbody?

Tags: spring-boot, post, httpclient

In my springboot project i use Httpclient to send http request,now i need to send a post request with request body like below:

```
{
  "entityFields": [
    {
      "type": "ENTITY_FIELD",
      "key": "name"
    }
  ],
  "entityFilter": {
    "type": "deviceType",
    "deviceType": "Battery"
  },
  "keyFilters": [
    {
      "key": {
        "key": "PACK_SN",
        "type": "TIME_SERIES"
      },
      "valueType": "STRING",
      "predicate": {
        "operation": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "defaultValue": "",
          "dynamicValue": null
        },
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageLink": {
    "page": 0,
    "pageSize": 10
  }
}
```

And i maybe need to change some value in the json data.
I know i can write a class that has the same structure as the json data when it is simple. Now the json data is pretty complex, so i wonder if i should do the same thing? if not,then how should i save the json request body and how to use it when i need to send the request?

Right before i just simpy copy the whole data as a String because the request body is fixed, now i some data have to change as parameter(like "defaultValue": "" can be set differently) i have to find another way to save the request body and send it as needed, but i am not sure how to do it correctly.